# Как обойти все файлы в папке и под папках используя java.nio

Tags: java

Я знаю как обойти все файлы использую рекурсию

```
        public static void getListFiles(String str) {
            File f = new File(str);
            for (File s : f.listFiles()) {
                if (s.isFile()) {
                    listWithFileNames.add(s);
                } else if (s.isDirectory()) {
                    getListFiles(s.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }

        }
```

А как получить список всех файлов используя методы из java.nio?

Answer (score 3):

Начиная с `Java 1.7`

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;

public class FileTree {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Path pathSource = Paths.get("Введите сюда путь к какому-либо каталогу, содержащему другие каталоги и файлы");
        try {
            Files.walkFileTree(pathSource, new MyFileVisitor());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class MyFileVisitor extends SimpleFileVisitor {
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path path,
                                     BasicFileAttributes fileAttributes) {
        System.out.println("file name:" + path.getFileName());
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path path,
                                             BasicFileAttributes fileAttributes) {
        System.out.println("Directory name:" + path);
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
}
```

[The Java™ Tutorials - Walking the File Tree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html)